# Engine hesitates when accelerating - 1996 Sunfire

Tags: engine, electrical, pontiac, sensor

I have a 1996 Pontiac Sunfire with the 2.2L engine. When I accelerate slowly the engine seems to run fine. However, if I accelerate quickly the engine seems to hesitate. I have already replaced the MAP sensor and the air intake/charge temperature sensor.

Is there something else I should try to resolve this issue?

Comment: When you say, hesitate, does it bog down, as in, takes a long time to speed up? Or does it bog for a second, then sort of take off? At this point, I'd be leaning towards a throttle position sensor.

Comment: Um, if I accelerate quickly it will be like I no longer have the power it usually does to accelerate and the car kind of shudders then usually will smooth out. It will also exhibit the same type symptoms if I am going up a hill and downshifts. Also, like I said if I accelerate gently it seems to be fine.

Comment: Sorry, if my description isn't the best. I'm not sure the best words to use to convey the symptoms I am seeing.

Comment: Your description is fine. I was just trying to help you get more, stuff you might not understand to explain. Are there any engine codes (check engine light - CEL)? When was the last time it had a sparkplug/wire/O2 change (how many miles ago)?

Comment: Spark plugs are new, and the plug wires are less than two years old (I don't remember exactly how long). It has been at least 5 years on the O2 sensor.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the Throttle Position Sensor, when those go out, there seems to be a delayed response.

Comment: Which is why I suggested it in my comment. TPS's don't usually go *bad* per se, but rather get dead spots in them. This is why they behave strangely when they do.

Comment: I replaced the throttle position sensor, and definitely have seen a difference (improvement) in throttle response. Will give it a few days of actual driving on it before declaring success.

Comment: Also test your distributor/coilpack. They usually only misbehave under high engine load until they're really bad and die outright.